# Bootstrap: Web page is keep on loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using [CSS Data Tables](https://datatables.net/), my code is below. I am using `Twitter Bootstrap`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="icons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title>BLA BLA BLA</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <link href="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <link href="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Responsive Style -->
    <link href="build/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
            <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
              <a href="index.html" class="site_title">Global Sea Foods</a>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>



            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

              <div class="sidenav">
                <button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="icon-search iconsp"><img src="images/icons-admin.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt=""></i> Super Admin 
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                  <a href="super-admin-settings.html">Super Admin Settings</a>
                  <a href="admin.html">Administrator Accounts</a>
                </div>
                <a href="mobile-admin-operations.html"><i class="icon-search iconsp"><img src="images/icons-gsfapp.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt=""></i> Mobile Staff</a>
                <a href="fresh-products.html"><i class="icon-search iconsp"><img src="images/icons-products.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt=""></i> Fresh Products</a>
                <button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="icon-search iconsp"><img src="images/icons-settings.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt=""></i> Product Settings 
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                  <a href="species.html">Species</a>
                  <a href="product-grades.html">Product Grades</a>
                  <a href="#">Product</a>
                  <a href="#">Product Type</a>
                  <a href="#">Product Specs</a>
                  <a href="#">Product Size</a>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /sidebar menu -->


          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- top navigation -->
        <div class="top_nav">
          <div class="nav_menu">
            <nav>
              <div class="nav toggle">
                <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
              </div><div class="nav-sm logo">Global Sea Foods</div>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="dropdown-toggle logbt" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="horiz">|</span> <span id="user-name">John Deo</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" href="#">Logout</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /top navigation -->

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">


          <div class="container">
          <div class="row title">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="main-titles">Fresh Products</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right padd10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sm-bt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addnewModal">Add Product</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel tile fixed_height_320">
                <h4>List of Products</h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="display" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Species</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Product Type</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Specs</th>
                        <th>Size</th>                        
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Delete</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbodystyle="height: 100px;">
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

        <!-- footer content -->
        <footer>
          <div class="">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </footer>
        <!-- /footer content -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add New-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="addnewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addnewModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title" id="addnewModalLabel">Add a New Fresh Product</h1>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="createaccount padd20">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Species</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Yellow Fin Tuna</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Product</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Loin</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Product Type</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Skin On</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Product Grade</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Grade B</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Product Specs</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Select Product Specs</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <label for="sel1">Select Product Size</label>
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>2-4 Kg</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary full-bt" id="update" value="Add Product">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add New-->
    <!-- Popup-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Fresh Product</h1>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 max-width">
                <div class="createaccount">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Yellow Fin Tuna</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option value="1" disabled selected>Grade 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Specs" placeholder="Skinless Boneless, Full Loins" value="Skinless Boneless, Full Loins">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group padd10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Size" placeholder="2-4 Kgs" value="2-4 Kgs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sm-bt" id="Edit Product" value="Edit Product">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end Popup-->
    <!-- popup Are You sure -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="remove" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="removeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title" id="removeLabel">Remove Product</h1>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="areyousure">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 popform-title" for="email">Are you sure you want to remove this product</div>
                      </div>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group padd20">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 mob-align max-width"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sm-bt green-bt" id="update" value="Yes"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sm-bt red-bt" id="update" value="No" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></div> 
                      </div>                     
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end popup Are You sure -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- Chart.js -->
    <script src="vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- gauge.js -->
    <script src="vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Skycons -->
    <script src="vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot -->
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <!-- Flot plugins -->
    <script src="vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
    <!-- DateJS -->
    <script src="vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
    <!-- JQVMap -->
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
    <script src="vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    $(".toggle-password").click(function() {

$(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
  input.attr("type", "text");
} else {
  input.attr("type", "password");
}
});


    </script>
<script>
  /* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am facing an issue I have never faced before, the web page is loading for a very long time! I noticed issue in Chrome Inspector. It is as below.

```
GET http://www.greenriverworks.com/elements/borders/green_button_background_over.jpg net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Fa  @   jquery.min.js:3
css @   jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:3
K   @   jquery.min.js:2
css @   jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:27
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
W   @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:27
Ja  @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:75
ja  @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:62
e   @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:106
(anonymous) @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:106
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
q   @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:96
f.fn.DataTable  @   jquery.dataTables.min.js:179
(anonymous) @   fresh-products.html:408
i   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery.min.js:2
J   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Some image from **greenriverworks.com** is loading forever, and I do not know what this website is. Seems a link available in one of the JS files.

When I removed my data table, specially the following part, everything is back to normal.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Maybe the iCheck skin is causing this? `<link href="vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @ChrisG: Tried removing that line. Nothing happens.